# How to Get Current date time which is not Depended on System date time and No Required internet

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, vb.net, winforms

How to Get Current date time which is not Depended on System date time  and NO Required internet using c# in Windows Application

Comment: Where would the date and time come from if not from the system or the Internet?

Comment: sir i tried to make a trial Version of Desktop Application So USER is Genius he can change its System Date so he can easily use Expired Application Once Again So This Application On Depended on System Date or Time

Comment: It's easier to do a Number of Free Trials than a time expired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know the answer.  Cannot be done.

So you need to change your strategy.

How to find out if someone is cheating the time clock?

You need to create a file that you can use as a reference.  Try this for starters, and if you need to, you can make this method both harder to detect, and harder for the user to overcome.

When you install your program, create a file, have the contents be the number of seconds since some random date according to the system time.  Now, once you run your program, check to make sure the clock hasn't gone backwards from that time.  If it has, PROBLEM!!!!, if it hasn't, update the file again.

The key here is to hide this file from the users you think will be cheating on you.  You might hide the information in the registry, or as part of a different file.  Hopefully, by the time the user recognizes you are storing the last time he ran, he won't be able to figure out how you are storing the time it was last ran, and won't be able to set the flag backwards.

This system seems very easy to beat, but only if the end user knows you are doing this, knows every place you are storing the information (store it in three different files, including c:\temp), and knows exactly how you are encrypting the last date it was run.  I don't know your audience, but my bet is that you are trying to prevent a teenager from using a trial version forever, and once the system is reasonably complex to beat (takes more than 5 minutes to defeat), you are pretty secure.

Another thing you can do is when you detect that an end user might be cheating, start deleting parts of your program so it doesn't run anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you cannot. If you are not picking the time from system or from internet then there is no way to get the current date time.

Comment: ohhhh ok sir ....HOw  can make trial Version Which User Can not use After Change date of system date??

Comment: @RushangPatel If you want to implement a time lockout, ask about that.  The question you asked has no usable answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you cannot use the system time, actually. If you think it might be inexact and the user needs to set it, that can of course be done from code. The following snippets show how to set the system code from C#:

```
[Serializable]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SystemTime
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public short Year;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public short Month;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public short DayOfWeek;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public short Day;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public short Hour;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public short Minute;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public short Second;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public short Milliseconds;
}
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetSystemTime(
[In] ref SystemTime lpSystemTime);

/// <summary>
/// Set the system time to the given date/time. 
/// The time must be given in utc.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dt">Date/time to set the system clock to</param>
/// <returns>True on success, false on failure. This fails if the current user has insufficient rights to set the system clock. </returns>
/// <remarks>This method needs administrative priviledges to succeed.</remarks>
public static bool SetSystemTimeUtc(DateTime dt)
{
    bool bSuccess = false;
    if (dt.Year >= 2100) // limit the year to prevent older C-routines to crash on the local time
    {
        dt = new DateTime(2099, dt.Month, dt.Day);
    }

    SystemTime st = DateTimeToSystemTime(dt);
    try
    {
        bSuccess = SetSystemTime(ref st);
    }
    catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        bSuccess = false;
    }
    catch (System.Security.SecurityException)
    {
        bSuccess = false;
    }

    return bSuccess;
}

private static SystemTime DateTimeToSystemTime(DateTime dt)
{
    SystemTime st;

    st.Year = (short)dt.Year;
    st.Day = (short)dt.Day;
    st.Month = (short)dt.Month;
    st.Hour = (short)dt.Hour;
    st.Minute = (short)dt.Minute;
    st.Second = (short)dt.Second;
    st.Milliseconds = (short)dt.Millisecond;
    st.DayOfWeek = (short)dt.DayOfWeek;

    return st;
}
```

As indicated in the comment above, this method needs the user to be administrator, otherwise it will fail.

Comment: i do already this  but i don't need this...USER can do for save trial version so he change system date so i need it

Comment: Ah... You want to avoid that the user can change the date/time setting to extend the lifetime of a trial version? Bad news then: Without an external source for the time that is basically impossible. You could try scanning the disk for files with never dates than the system time, but that's a lengthy process and might not be right (perhaps the system time was corrected because it indeed was wrong before).